# How can i implement simple boost.asio mulsticast sender?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, udp, boost-asio, multicast

I want to use boost.asio to create a multicast UDP sender.
I have a my thread and I want to use boost only for:

- socket;
- send();
- Error Handling;

Can you suggest something?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? Can you post some code that you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple to accomplish.  Here's a basic class that handles most of everything you need using synchronous calls:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class MulticastSender
{
public:
   MulticastSender(const boost::asio::ip::address& multicast_addr,
      const unsigned short multicast_port)
         : ep_(multicast_addr, multicast_port)
   {
      socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(svc_, ep_.protocol()));
   }

   ~MulticastSender()
   {
      socket_.reset(NULL);
   }

public:
   void send_data(const std::string& msg)
   {
      socket_->send_to(
         boost::asio::buffer(msg.str()), ep_);
   }

private:
   boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint                  ep_;
   boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket_;
   boost::asio::io_service                         svc_;
};
```

This simple class meets 2 of your 3 requirements (no error handling).  To use it, simply create an instance of it in an appropriate place, and your thread implementation just calls MulticastSender::send_data() to send the multicast data to the associated endpoint.

Comment: This won't compile, msg.str() is wrong and even if it was c_str() it wouldn't work with send_to().

Answer (score 1):

Did you give a try to the samples?

```
<boost>\libs\asio\example\multicast\
```

It contains sampples for

```
receiver.cpp
sender.cpp
```

Comment: I had seen examples of multicast sender, but perhaps not what
I need.
I now have my own thread (I must use this implementation of
thread). I would like to use boost only for the socket:
if I look at the sender as I understand that there is something
asynchronous: You can use some thread?
I noticed this:

void handle_send_to(const boost::system::error_code& error);
void handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error);

It's possibile to use synchronous sockets?

Comment: @GgSalent it is not clear to me what you're asking in your comment. Maybe try clarifying your original question, or asking a new question?